# Finding the limit of a sequence with unknowns

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\alpha n^3+\beta n^2+1}{\alpha n^2+4n+2 }$$

I need to find the limit in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
$$a_n=\frac{n^2(αn+β+\frac{1}{n^2})}{n^2(α+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2})}=\frac{αn+β+\frac{1}{n^2}}{α+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}$$ Now, take cases $α>0, α<0$ and $α=0$.

Comment: You are welcome. I assume you mean n goes to infinity?

Comment: Yes, n goes to infinity.